# Set the width and height for a TTLauncherItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, three20, dimensions, ttlauncheritem

I have this:

```
_launcherView.pages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [[[TTLauncherItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Note"
                                                         image:@"bundle://Icon.png"
                                                           URL:@"http://www.google.com/" canDelete:NO] autorelease],
                        [[[TTLauncherItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"To Do Items"
                                                         image:@"bundle://Icon.png"
                                                           URL:@"http://www.yahoo.com/" canDelete:NO] autorelease],
                        nil],
                       nil];
```

How can I set the width and height for the items? I want all items to be 64x64 pixels.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have full control over the item by using registered stylesheets. Simply register your own default stylesheet, then override the `TTDefaultStylesheet` method:

```
- (TTStyle*)launcherButton:(UIControlState)state;
```